# Ajax in Rails: replace many elements to many elements

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have `@posts` here, and when user clicks the button, which triggers the ajax, @post change to another `@other_posts`. ERB may look like this

```
    <div class="posts">
      <% @posts.each do |post| %>
          <%= post.title %>
      <% end %>  
    </div>
```

generated html

```
    <div class="posts">
          post1 title
          post2 title
          post3 title 
    </div>
```

After the Ajax, html should look like

```
    <div class="posts">
          post4 title
          post5 title
          post6 title 
    </div>
```

How can I do it in AJAX? Something like `$(@posts).replaceWith(@other_posts);`,but is array here.

I think it would be easy to make a partial for `<div class="posts">`, and the call `replaceWith()`, but does it feel ugly?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Can you rewrite the question to make it simpler?

Comment: I update my question, is it simpler now?

Comment: How do you expect this to work? `$(@posts).replaceWith(@other_posts);`

Comment: Well...I mean if its just one element for one element,  `$(".post").replaceWith(".another_post');` but here we are replacing array with array(@post to @other_posts), and I have no idea about it, which is the problem that I'm asking.

Comment: I think what will solve your problem in pagination with ajax http://railscasts.com/episodes/174-pagination-with-ajax

Comment: you really have to get a grip on what happens on the server side (erb rendering) and on the client side (javascript) and what the differences are.